On injective resolutions of modules over complex Lie algebras
Let $M$ be a module over a complex Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$. Assume there exists an element $X$ that acts injectively on $M$.
Question: $\operatorname{Ext}^{i}_{\mathfrak{g}}(\mathbb{C}, M) = 0$ for all $i = 0, 1, 2, \dots$?
Or even more strongly:
Question: Does there exist an injective resolution
$$
0 \to M \to I_{0} \to I_{1} \to I_{2} \to \ldots
$$
consisting of injective modules $I_{k}$, where $X$ acts injectively on $M$?

Maybe I am missing something, but as currently formulated, the second question does not appear to be stronger than the first (in the sense that an affirmative answer to the second would imply an affirmative answer to the first), because any module admits an injective resolution?
